# Uploading files to Amazon CloudFront instead of Amazon S3 using iphone or iPad

Tags: iphone, amazon-web-services, ipad, amazon-cloudfront

I am able to upload files to Amazon S3 from iPhone. But its taking too much of time to upload 100 audio files. So I thought to use CloudFront for uploading files because Amazon supports PUT request.

So can you please explain how to upload audio files to Amazon CloudFront instead of Amazon S3 using iPhone or iPad?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

The PUT feature of CloudFront is simply a pass through to the origin - in this case S3.  It's intended for you to be able to put CloudFront in front of your website to increase download speeds, but still allow your users to post form data and the like to your origin servers.  What your seeking to do isn't really a primary use case.

If you try what you want to do, your mobile apps will be connecting to a cloudfront server, which may be slightly geographically closer to the user, but the cloudfront server still needs to pass the data through to the S3 service. 
The throughput into S3 is likely much higher than the mobile bandwidth available to your users.  So whether you're uploading to S3 or CloudFront, your bandwidth limit will likely be capped by the mobile network.

If you did want to pursue this option, you would need to whitelist the [Authorization](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html) header in your CloudFront distribution so that S3 will allow your upload requests.

But before you go this route (which again i believe will be a lot of work for little return), did you:

1. Did you ensure that you're uploading to an S3 bucket that is allocated in the nearest geographical region to your users?
2. Did you try using [S3 MultiPart Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html)?

Answer (score 0):

It's could be achieved from a a similar techinque to cloudfront which is called "S3 Accelerate". If the bucket's region is far away from the uploading computer you can upload faster by enabling S3 Accelerate on your bucket and then uploads will go directly through the Amazon server closest to you and then continues sending the file from there to the bucket's actual region at an optimal route.
You use it by uploading to "bucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com". You can read about it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html).